# nginx proxy_pass doesn't work for included files

Tags: nginx

I have a service running on some random domain (let's say `example.com`) and I want to make a simple facade from my local machine (a.k.a `localhost`).

```
location /some-app {
  # This is for LDAP auth, not sure if important
  auth_ldap_servers ldapserver;

  proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

I am certain it does redirect my requests to that `example.com` page, but it does not get the files linked from the `example.com` index, like the CSS and JavaScript files. I get stuff like:

```
172.17.0.1 - email@address.com [11/Aug/2016:10:20:35 +0000] "GET /components/navbar/navbar.controller.js HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "http://localhost:8080/some-app" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
```

I have tried playing with `proxy_set_header Host $host;`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I'm quite sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't really tell what. I've seen `rewrite` rules, but I was thinking it might be easier than that.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  ldap_server ldapserver {
    # boring ldap config 
  }

  ldap_server ldapserver2 {
    # boring ldap config
  }

  server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    auth_ldap_servers ldapserver;

    location / {
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /some-app {
      auth_ldap_servers ldapserver2;

      proxy_pass http://example.com:9000;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root html;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What is your full nginx configuration? And where are the static resources located in your system?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen You have the full nginx config above. As for the static resources, I'm not sure what you mean, but if you're referring to that `/components/navbar/navbar.controller.js` file, then that should come from `example.com:9000`, it's not hosted locally.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Updated according to comment.

The following configuration servers only the `index.html` from nginx, all other requests are passed to the application server.

Instead of:

```
location / {
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

location /some-app {
    auth_ldap_servers ldapserver2;

    proxy_pass http://example.com:9000;
}
```

You should use:

```
location / {
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
    auth_ldap_servers ldapserver2;

    proxy_pass http://example.com:9000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this indeed works fine. Maybe I didn't explain properly - there will be an index page, at `location /` (a static page), and the `/some-app` location should point to that `example.com:9000` address. Basically, I want it to work exactly as you suggested, just at `/some-app`. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I updated the answer according to the detail you provided.

Comment: I now get `"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65`. :( And also, maybe I'm getting this wrong, but wouldn't this mean that whatever link I go to, it would redirect to that `example.com` app?

Comment: True.. Actually I cannot figure out how to do this in nginx. As usually static resources like `.js`, `.css` and image files are served directly from nginx, I don't know how to do this kind of thing with nginx.